# Implicit differentiation in multivariable calculus - example that makes no sense - $F(x,y) = xy+y^2-8x+16$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am asked to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ given that

$$xy+y^2-8x+16=0$$

at the point where $x=-1$.

I do find that

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{8-y}{x+2y}$$

but what should I substitute for $y$? If I plug $x=-1$ on the equation given i get no real answer for $y$.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: At a glance I'd agree that there is no point $(-1,y)$ that lies on the curve, so yeah, the problem doesn't make sense. Possibly a typo?

Comment: @abc yes, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Community answer so the question can be marked as closed:

As abc remarked in a comment, you're right that there is no point $(-1,y)$ on the curve.